# One UILabel in a set of three won't update text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have three UILabel's I'm updating after some data is returned to me through a GET url request. The first two label's update their text fine upon obtaining the data, the third label won't update its text until I tap on the label. I have already checked and all of my labels are being updated on the main thread as UIKit demands, but I can't figure out why one of three labels, all set up the same way, is not updating itself as expected.

Comment: Can you share your code? That'll cut down the guess work.

Comment: @Adeel I fixed it. The label wasn't getting a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when a UILabel doesn't have an explicit width, and its text gets set to "", the label effectively gets 0 width and then doesn't reexpand when the text gets edited. Giving my label a defined width fixed the problem. The other two labels weren't having a problem because their values were never "", but were 0.0 instead so they always had some text in them.